# How to interpret the rate constants of in-vivo racemization of thalidomide?

Tags: kinetics, stereochemistry, chirality

The article by Eriksson *et. al.* found that thalidomide undergoes chiral inversion in vivo. It found the mean rate constants too, $0.17~\mathrm{h^{-1}}$ (*R* to *S*) and $0.12~\mathrm{h^{-1}}$ (*S* to *R*).

I have no idea what those numbers mean. Does that mean 17% of the *R*-thalidomide becomes *S*-thalidomide every hour?

**Reference**
[Eriksson, T.; Bjöurkman,S.; Roth, B.; Fyge, Å; Höuglund, P; *Chirality* **1995,** *7* (1), 44-52.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/chir.530070109) ([PubMed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7702998))

Comment: Woo. It does look better. I noticed you italized *R* and *S*. Was it with asterisks?. Had you used `$R$` instead, would it become bold and italic?

Comment: The `$` signs invoke mathematical mode, where you can typeset formulae with special commands. A short description is given in the second link above.  It takes some time to learn but it can be incredibly helpful. The `*` belong to the markdown set that is used on the site. Visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to learn more. This one is much easier to learn. If you have any questions that are not part of the [help], then visit [meta].